# Delete EBS volumes not in use without losing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume

I have created a ec2 instance and attached 4 ebs volumes, gp2=3gb, gp3=3, io1=4gb, io2=4 and mounted it.

I have installed postgres source code on it and created a database with 2 million sample entries.

By checking, I see that the table or data which i am creating is been stored in root volume xvda1.

I want to delete rest 4 volumes that I have attached to an instance in such a way that it won;t affect the postgresdata.  The root volume says 36% use and the rest 4 volumes says 2% use and I think the 2% is storage use to mount it ( not sure ).  I wanna know how can i delete it,

1. should I umount it first and then detach the volume and delete it?

[image: Picture]

Comment: your data is in root volume.  and if the rest attached volume is empty you can detach it from instance and safely delete it

Comment: @Barun thanks for the answer, Do it need to umount it first  or directly I can detach it and then delete it.

Comment: It's better to umount it first for graceful release otherwise might get issue at the time of next restart or create new instance using the AMI of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

As your data is in root volume, you can remove all other volumes.
For graceful unmounting & preserving data integrity, unmount drives one by one & then delete it. Once all done, just restart your EC2 & check if all your data is still there.